# The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer

Tags: keyrings

Some program always asks for my login password. I do not know what causes this. How can I stop it?

[image: Unlock Login Keyring prompt]

Answer (score 21):

I presume that you must have turned on the "Auto-login" option on, when you turn it on, to unlock the login-key-ring (the place where your passwords are stored for chrome and other applications), you need to enter the password that you have setup for your account. I always get prompted with this when I am trying to open Chrome for the first time after booting up Ubuntu-Gnome. It asked me to set up the password for this key ring but I believe that it won't ask for Ubuntu Unity and it's the default password that you used to log-in in to your account.

I wouldn't recommend disabling this feature because it will unlock your key-ring without the password. However, [here is how to turn it off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot).

Comment: "the password that you have setup for your account"... what account?

Comment: -1, because the question was "how", not "why not". Not that it mattered for a duplicate, but just trying to save a a bit of time for future readers.

Comment: @Klesun
Being a future reader, I found the answer very helpful. If someone want to commit a suicide and asks for the best method on some stack exchange site and some one starts to explain why he shouldn't do it, you gonna down vote his/her answer, too? ;)

Comment: Yes, you downvote, because it is super annoying to constantly be patronized and most of all NOT ANSWERING the question precisely, as it is written. If I aks why, I will do that. I know exactly what I'm asking, every word of it, I'm not confused why I want to do it, you just waste my time if you treat me like an imbecile. Stackexchange is a precise question / answer site and will beat you over the head if not following this in other places. A why answer is as useful as people on Amazon answering posted questions with "I don't know". Why not answer unbidden about "where" or "when"? /S

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense, actually. I have a disk encryption with the same password as my login ones, and there is an option where you can skip the first login (Ubuntu -> [Settings/User/Automatic Login]). So I did that because I had to write the same password 2 times on boot, and it works. However, this problem appeared, and I didn't connect the dots at the beginning. Apparently, the disk encryption has nothing to do with the OS functioning :) Thank you @Hashik