# Ubuntu - Different after reboot?

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, drivers, sound, reboot

After working on my dual-booted Ubuntu (17.10) partition on my lenovo X1C5 yesterday; I decided to not shut it down and just put it to sleep closing the lid.

Today, when I opened the lid, the laptop was shutdown - obviously it lost power.
After putting it to charge and booting up the Ubuntu partition there were several things that were different:

- The resolution on the lock-screen changed (back to default I guess?)
- My terminal went from the default black/purple to some weird white.
- When on terminal, the mouse turns out te be tiny and plain black
- My chrome session didn't remember my open pages (thankfully I could recover them) and had me logged out.

  - No extensions were loaded (I guess that came from the fact that it started chrome as logged-out?)

Any idea what happend? Also how can I get the default terminal back?

Edit:
Whenver I reboot, when logging in **with** my password, I now get the message

> the login keyring did not get unlocked

And I have to retype the password.

Also it seems most drivers disappeaered - I can't play any sounds, only sound output device is "Unix FIFO sink /home/...."
--> Seems the sound-device isn't listed at all under hardware devices!

Answer (score 0):

When laptop suspends (sleep mode) it goes in a low power mode keeping all your opened programs' data in RAM, and when it ran out of battery and shut down it could have been in the process of writing some data, all I can tell is not only you you lost some data which weren't saved but also got important files and settings corrupted thus the system could not understand what those half-written data were and set most things back to default or whatever.

It's always best to hibernate if you're going away for a long time so the OS saves all your data on your hard disk.

And also, about the keyrin issue, it seems like Ubuntu automatically turned on Auto-login. Refer to the answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918712/the-login-keyring-did-not-get-unlocked-when-you-logged-into-your-computer).