# Location of 'Default keyring' file in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: files, default, keyrings, location

`~/.local/share/keyrings/*.keyring` file is responsible for personal/user/login keyring.

There is another file somewhere in the system responsible for 'Default keyring'. For example, lightdm may ask for a password to unlock this 'Default keyring' right on the desktop "welcome login" screen (in my case to decrypt passphrase required to bring up a wired/wireless network connection).

I want to know where this 'Default keyring' file is located.

Thank You!

Comment: `seahorse` allows me to manage personal/user/login keyring, but not the one I'm interested in

Comment: @Terrance The response there suggests `~/.gnome2/...`, but this dir is empty on my system.
I know for sure, that there must be another file, because I know passwords for 'Login' and 'Default keyring' and two passwords are different. `seahorse` allows me to manage only 'Login' keyring.

Comment: Your login password is stored in the `/etc/shadow` file and is encrypted there.

Comment: Thank You @Terrance ! I know that there is `/etc/shadow` storing single login password for each user, but a keyring named 'Login' on my system allows to store multiple passwords and data. My system has one more keyring which is called 'Default keyring' - and I need to know location of that file.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding.  The Login part of the keyring is that which is Unlocked when you login.  It has nothing to do with your Login Password.  Open Seahorse and mouse over the item.  It will tell you that.  There is only one keyring file per user on a system.

Comment: @Terrance Pls, read the question again: my system is asking me to unlock password for keyring named 'Default keyring' right on the lightdm welcome screen, even BEFORE I or anyone else got logged in. And I know for sure, that keyring named 'Default keyring' in something different from the keyring named 'Login', because I can only unlock them using different passwords.

Comment: Correct, there is a password that is set for the keyring access when you first set it up.  If you change your password by using the `passwd` command, you have to go back into seahorse and update your password there.   Right click on the Login part and choose Change Password to match so that they are the same again so it stops asking you.

Comment: @Terrance `seahorse` allows me to manage keyring named 'Login' and (disclosure!) the password for my 'Login' keyring already matches to my login password. I know for sure that keyring named 'Default keyring' can only be unlocked using a different password.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/867/231142

Comment: I've read all the Q&A yesterday before asking this question. For example, in the link you've just posted people talk about 'Login' keyring. There is also feature of `seahorse` itself, which allows to manage several personal/user keyrings and set one of them as a default. And this becomes really confusing when you need to find (like I am) a keyring named 'Default keyring'.

Comment: I think 'Default' is just a term.  I am only aware of the one keyring file per user.  I have searched my system up and down looking for more keyrings, and they do not exist other than `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring`.  Everywhere I have looked all points back to the login.keyring file in your home folder.