# How to configure to login without password through remote shell

Tags: login, password, lightdm

I'm using Ubuntu16.04 and I need to login desktop environment without password.

I have to do the configuration throught remote shell, meaning that I can't do this by clicking "System Settings --- User Accounts --- Automatic Login".

I just googled my question and found a method: `vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and edit it as below:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=USERNAME
```

I tried, it works.

However, now when I do something, a window will popup:
[image]

This will block what I'm doing unless I enter the password.
How to remove this window?

---

OR, is it possible to do "clicking System Settings --- User Accounts --- Automatic Login" through remote shell?

I've read this:
[How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

But what I need is to configure all through remote shell. I can't configure through desktop.

Comment: @muru   I have to do all things through remote shell, I have no desktop to do configure.

Comment: There is a command line answer that simply deletes the keyring

Comment: @muru   `rm ~/.local/share/keyring/*` doesn't work for me. I've found a solution and I'll pose an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing `lightdm.conf`, I just need to disable the keyring through remote shell.

I've found a solution as below:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon-old
sudo killall gnome-keyring-daemon
```