# Bypass Gui password for desktop launcher

Tags: 18.04, launcher

I'm a new here, but a long term viewer.

I have created a desktop shortcut (pic#1), that shortcut will start a script

```
    #! /bin/sh
remmina -c /home/info/.remmina/1454065572442.remmina
```

But when I click on the launcher for the first time, the system asks for a password.

[image: 2]

How can I disable the password prompt?

I have done `chmod +777` on both the script and the launcher.

Thank you!

Comment: Put that command in the `sudoers` file to stop that behaviour

Comment: And why would remmina be asking for login details from your home directory?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Found the Solution!
see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot Thank you!