# Ubuntu 22.04 Remote Desktop from Windows

Tags: sharing, rdp, connection-sharing, desktop-sharing

I activate my remote desktop in Ubuntu 22.04 but when I try connect through Windows 10, after ask the password appears `Authentication error has occurred` appears.

[image: Remote desktop screen]

Comment: Please reiterate the question once again removing the spelling errors. Describe it in a little detail so that other users can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
Authentication error has occurred
```

Is probably because of VNC's TLS encryption that is not always supported by remote clients.

Solutions ...

#### Recommended

Use a remote desktop client/app that supports TLS encryption.

#### Not recommended

This was an issue with the older Ubuntu releases when connecting from Windows remote desktop app and a workaround was to disable encryption with:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

In newer releases, however, the only possible way to do that is to [disable encryption in the default key-ring by setting a blank password for the key-ring authentication](https://askubuntu.com/q/867) ... This however brings with it some serious security hazards so, **be careful**.