# Headless computer (Update 2)

Tags: login, headless

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, GNOME  42.9, Windowing X11.

I can turn off the monitor but if I restart the OS I can't log back in with Windows RDT, and my goal is to never have to plug a monitor into this Optiplex 5060.

I would also like to be able to run at a higher resolution than the current 1024x768, I'll ask for help in a new post to not mix things up.

---

I'm new to Linux and haven't been able to find an answer to this.

I have an Optiplex SFF computer that I use to learn Ubuntu and I would alos like to have as a backup to my Windows PC along with being headless.

Problem is that I have to login on that computer before I can connect via mstsc (remote desktop) from my Windows PC.

Setting > Users > Automatic Login is no help at all. When this is set to on you get a different login screen "authentication required, the login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer"

I am aware that I may need a Display Port "plug".

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: What do you need that auto login doesn't do? Please be specific.

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: That keyring popup is not a login screen. There are probably 100 questions here about unlocking the keyring after auto login. Search this site.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/867/243321