# How do I set up automatic login?

Tags: 10.04, gdm

How do I get 10.04 (Lucid) to log me in automatically on each reboot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find this option under `System > Administration > Login Screen`.

You'll need to "unlock" the window as this requires administrative privileges.

[image]

You can then select the user and session you would like logged in automatically.

[image]