# Auto login as guest

Tags: login, automatic

Trying do find out if I can setup ubuntu to automatically login as guest when the machine is rebootet, skipping the login screen.

I belive that was possible in 10.04 or thereabouts through Settings >Administration > Login screen, but this option seems to have been moved.

Thread for 10.04 [How do I set up automatic login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5264/how-do-i-set-up-automatic-login/709855#709855)

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with your favorite editor & under the section [SeatDefaults] add:

```
allow-guest=true  
autologin-guest=true  
autologin-user-timeout=0  
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin  
user-session=ubuntu
```

If nothing is there yet, just paste the lines into the file and save.